How to index a matrix with letters?
I'm trying to create with java a 7x7 matrix with numbers and letters as indexes to locate each cell. To understand it better, I'm making a field for the naval battle. The problem is that I can't align the letters with the columns in the array. Do you have any ideas? Of course, the letters are outside the matrix, so it's a printing problem. I can't use any kind of GUI.
System.out.print("   A B C    D    E    F     G \n");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
                        System.out.print((i + 1) + "  ");
                        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
                            System.out.print(campo[i][j] + "  ");
                        }
                        System.out.println(" " + (i + 1));
                    }
                    System.out.print("   A B C    D    E    F     G \n");

I tried to write letters manually with the print function, but they are not aligned to the matrix's columns.
EDIT: I'm trying to fill the matrix with this '⛶', and even if I modify the format parameters, the letters aren't aligned.
This is how it look like
      A    B    C    D    E    F    G
  1   ⛃   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛁    1
  2   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶    2
  3   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶    3
  4   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶    4
  5   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶    5
  6   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶    6
  7   ⛁   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛶   ⛃    7


Please show expected output.  Also what does the campo  array contain?

Check out System.out.printf to specify formatting parameters like width. Then you can do it like this. Here I am using a default numeric array for campo.
final int COLUMNS = 7;
final int ROWS = 7;

int[][] campo = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
System.out.print("    ");
for (int i = 0; i < COLUMNS; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%4c", 'A' + i);
}
System.out.println();

for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) {
    System.out.printf("%4d", r+1);
    for (int c = 0; c < COLUMNS; c++) {
        System.out.printf("%4s", campo[r][c]);
    }
    System.out.printf("%4d%n", r+1);
}

See this code run at Ideone.com.
       A   B   C   D   E   F   G
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3
   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4
   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5
   6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6
   7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7


thanks a lot, you saved my mental health

@BasilBourque I had to edit my question because I noticed other issues. Anyway I can't upvote because I need at least 15 reputation

@vinc The particular character does not matter. Use a monospaced font in your terminal/console app  so that all characters are the same width. Adapt the code seen here in this Answer to use strings rather than integers: String[][] campo.

@BasilBourque I'm sorry to bother you but I don't understand how to set a monospaced font into a matrix. I did some research and I haven't found nothing useful for my situation. Anyway my matrix campo is already a string type. Thanks for your patience

@vinc You run this app in a tool, an app that provides a terminal or console text-based display. Perhaps this is the console within an IDE. That app uses a particular font to display its text. In virtually all such tools, (a) that font should default to a monospaced font, and (b) you the user can override that default font to specify another font. Be sure your app is not set to a proportional font. That would explain columns not aligning visually despite aligning logically (certain number of SPACE characters padding).

@vinc Example: Font settings in IntelliJ. Font settings in Terminal app on macOS.
